# How to allow my community, without owning the storefront create their own auctions using the auction-house framework?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I am looking for a way to allow my community to create their own auctions on my storefront, how is this possible?

Comment: There is no function that allows it. You could build something that adds a wallet as authority maybe... I would not recommend that though.
Also be aware that storefront v2 (which is way better and faster) will be released soon TM

Comment: @MarkSackerberg Looking forward to the storefront v2, im assuming it will have the authority I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Mark Sackerberg's comment, v1 storefront is deprecated and auction-house v2 framework is probably what you should targeting for any new projects.

There is no official UI for auction house yet. However, the auction house framework itself (with the underlying contracts) is good to go and can be found here:

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/auction-house

The command line client for auction house is here:

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/master/js/packages/cli/src/auction-house-cli.ts

You can use the examples from the cli to build your own UI.

Alternatively, metaplex are preparing the official auction house reference implementation UI. We are told that should be available fairly soon even though the official release date has not yet been confirmed.

Depending on your timelines, skillset and learning appetite, you may want to roll your own UI. In that case, the above links are a good place to start.  Or else you can wait for the official UI reference implementation.